# How to make a virtual drone creator?

Tags: python, api, 3d

as a noob I just finished my personal project(drone renting website made with HTML,CSS,Javascript)

The question is **how** to make a virtual drone creator where users can choose parts and visualize them on a 3d image? (ex. Nike id shoes creator)

**What** programs can be used to achieve this goal and what arguments should i study to achieve  it? Do you have any blueprint how can this be done? Do you think it's possible to make it alone with little knowledge but a big motivation ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nike uses ThreeJS, I've just looked at its source code.